# Allow user to create and manage other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I have a user model, called **Account** {id, name, address, email, password, etc ... }, and I want to be able to allow that user to create and manage other users. I created a **Relationships** model, {manager_id, care_id, relationship, etc ... } to keep track of the relations between the user and other managed  users. Basically, a user `has_many relationships through: :relationships, source: "care_id"` . From what I understand, a new user has to be created first, to get a new user id, before you can build a relationship. A normal user, when sign up, will require validations of email, password, etc ... however, for the managed users, all you need is a name, and they can go back edit everything else later.

What's the best/correct way to implement such functions. Do I need a new controller? Or, can I just add new actions to the default User controller? How do I create new users, without the normal validations of the User model (name, email, password can't be empty, have to be certain length, etc ...). How can the relationships be automatically created with the correct user ids. Thanks in advance for your help and/or pointing me to the right direction.

The idea is this: A user can sign up and manage his account. He can then create a "care" account, which basically only require a name to get started, and doesn't need other validations since the child account won't be using email/password to login. If the child account later want access, the parent account can set the email/password for it then, and it will become a full account. This parent account, manager, can also invite another account, maybe a spouse, to act as another manager for this child account.

**UPDATE:** Some more information:

*Account Model*

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :email, presence: true, 
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                length:     { maximum: 32 },
                unless: :child?

has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "manager_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :cares, through: :relationships, source: :care
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "care_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
has_many :managers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :manager
...
def child?
  false
end

class CareUser < Account

 def child?
   true
 end
end
```

*Relationship Model*

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :care_id, :manager_id, :type

 belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Account"
 belongs_to :care, class_name: "Account"

 validates :manager_id, presence: true
 validates :care_id, presence: true
end
```

*Cares Controller*

```
class CaresController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @cares = current_user.cares
  end

  def new
    @user = CareUser.new
    @care = Relationship.new
  end

  def create
    @user = CareUser.new(params[:first_name])
    logger.info @user.inspect
    if @user.save(false)
      @care = current_user.relationships.build(current_user.id, @user.id, params[:relation])
      if @care.save
        flash[:success] = "New care has been successfully added."
      else
        flash[:error] = "Failed"
        render action: new
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed adding user"
      render action: new
    end

  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

When `@user = CareUser.new` I get `uninitialized constant CaresController::CareUser`, the subclass ... but no error is displayed if it set it to `@user = Account.new`, the parent class.

*The submit form, cares/new.html.erb*

Not sure what the correct way to set up the form, but since submitting to two models, I used `form_tag` instead of `form_for`. Currently I can't seem to get the form to submit correctly, not sure if the problem is in the form, the model or the controller.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <h1>New care</h1>
    <%=  form_tag("/cares", method: :post) do %>
        <% if @user.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "errors") %>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <% if @care.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@care.errors.count, "errors") %>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <% @care.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= label_tag(:first_name, "First name:") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:first_name) %>

        <%= label_tag(:relation, "Relationship") %>
        <%= select_tag(:relation, options_for_select([ ["Son", "1"], ["Daughter", "2"], ["Father", "3"], ["Mother", "4"], ["Grandson", "5"], ["Granddaughter", "6"], ["Grandfather", "7"], ["Grandmother", "8"] ])) %>


        <br>
        <%= submit_tag("Create care account") %>


    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create this structure to manage the users hierarchy with infinite levels:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_relations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subordinates, :through => :user_relations
  has_many :inverse_user_relations, :class_name => "UserRelation", :foreign_key => "subordinate_id"
  has_many :superiors, :through => :inverse_user_relations, :source => :user
  ...
end

class UserRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subordinate, :class_name => "User"
end

manager.subordinates = [subordinate_one, subordinate_two]
subordinate_one.superiors #manager user
manager.subordinates.size #2 users
admin.subordinates << manager
manager.superiors #admin user
admin.subordinates.size #1 user
```

Then, to manage user permissions and validations you can use a combination of 
[cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem and a hierarchy of users to execute validations related with each user type.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  #and other common validations
end

class Subordinate < User
  #specific validations for this user type
end

class OtherUser < User
  #specific validations for this user type
end
```

Then in the UsersController, you can create do something like this:

```
def create
  @user = Subordinate.new(params[:user])
  @user.save
end
```

or

```
def create
  @user = OtherType.new(params[:user])
  @user.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The user structure is exactly what I want, with multiple levels, up and down. I created another controller because I need another create action. The original create action is already being define for the default user. Can you tell me how to set up the form to submit and process the information?

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you should mark it as correct and ask another question for the rest...

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement,

```
I have a user model {id, name, address, email, password, etc ... }, and I want to be able to allow that user to create and manage other users.
```

If you just want to keep track of who the manager for the user is, the solution is to have '**manager_id**' column in users table itself. If manager_id IS NULL, then the user himself is a top manager, otherwise the corresponding managers id.

In case you need to store more details on the relationship, then you need to create a separation association table **user_managers** and say

**user has_many :managers, through user_mangers.**

in these cases, you don't have to create user record first always. Whenever you create a new user, I assume you assign a manager for that user, if needed.

```
manager = User.first
user = User.new
user_manager = manager.user_managers.new
user_manager.student = user
user.save!
```

user_managers table structure:

```
 id, user_id, student_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do need to store additional information, such as the relation from one account to another (son, daughter, father, mother, etc ...). Can you help with setting up the form to submit the information correctly?